# Json data into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
var test=[];
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
                $.each(data,function(key,value){
                    test.push(value.topic);
                });
            });
        });
```

Here is my javacript code. I want to push json object's all values with key as topic. But when I try to access test[i] (i be any integer within array length) I get an error "undefined" . What' am I msissing?

Here is my json object sample-

```
[
        {
            "topic": "Books",
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "topic": "Grossery",
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "topic": "stationery",
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "topic": "food",
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "topic": "market items",
            "quantity": 3
        }
]
```

Comment: Where are you accessing it?

Comment: You might be accessing outside the async function that is why you are getting `undefined`

Comment: I am accessing it after the line where function ends. But if I access whole array instead of specific value then it's working fine

Comment: Learn to debug, print the values of `data  key value and test` at each call to function. You will understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working fine for me.

Are you accessing the data before the callback that you pass to `getJson` has been executed?

Here's an example that works if I serve it locally using `python3 -m http.server 8080`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var test=[];
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
                $.each(data,function(key,value){
                    test.push(value.topic);
                });
                // only use test array after data has been loaded
                doWork();
            });
        });
        function doWork() {
            $('#output').text(
                test + ' ' + test[0]
            );
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to access the test array just before the script tag ends?

Comment: No, the access happens inside the callback passed to `getJSON`. You can sequence your actions after the callback by wrapping them in a function and calling that function from the callback. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the following working code:

```js
var data = [
        {
            "topic": "Books",
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "topic": "Grossery",
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "topic": "stationery",
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "topic": "food",
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "topic": "market items",
            "quantity": 3
        }
]
var test = [];
$.each(data,(i,v) => test.push(v.topic));
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to fetch the json data instead of creating a json object in javascript file

Comment: Your code seems that you have created an object and copied the values itself

Comment: I am assuming you got correct data that you showed from your `$.getJSON()` call